# MVVM Light Silverlight Question

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

Hi I've been getting started with MVVM in Silverlight. When you call your model from your viewmodel the model's call to it's Web Service is asynchronous. What is the best way of notifying the view model when you have your data. Currently I just use the messenger class to fire it back a notification with the data set up a listener on the viewmodel. This works fine but I'm not sure it's the best way of doing it. Can anyone point me in the direction of some best practices? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) for that. Specifically, take a look at the Subject class.